# When is a row added to DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT?

Tags: oracle, awr

I don't understand the criteria that entails an additional record in the `dba_hist_sqlstat` view. I have expected there to be at most one entry per `sql_id` and `snap_id`, that is, the following statement to return no record:

```
select 
  count(*),
  snap_id,
  sql_id
from
  dba_hist_sqlstat
group by
  snap_id,
  sql_id
having
  count(*) > 1
order by
  count(*) desc;
```

*Yet*, it returns many records, indicating that it is not possible, but the normality, that the same sql statement is captured multiple times per `snap_id`.

Additionaly, with more than one record per sql and snap period, how do I interpret the *delta* columns within this view? The documentation reads:

> The delta value is the value of the statistics from the BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME to the END_INTERVAL_TIME in the DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT view.

This doesn't really make sense to me.

**Update** as per *Justin's* comment: this is not in a RAC environment: so even if I `group by snap_id, sql_id, dbid, instance_number`, the query returns multiple records per snap_id and sql_id.

Comment: Is this a RAC database?  If you add `DBID` and `INSTANCE_NUMBER` to the `GROUP BY`, are you still getting duplicate rows?

Comment: @JustinCave: This is not an RAC database (I have updated the question accordingly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle collects SQL statistics for each SQL execution plan/sql_id (`plan_hash_value`), rather than just for a specific `sql_id`.

To verify that this is indeed the case, this query should return 0 rows:

```
select 
  count(*),
  snap_id,
  sql_id,
  plan_hash_value
from
  dba_hist_sqlstat
group by
  snap_id,
  sql_id,
  plan_hash_value
having
  count(*) > 1
order by
  count(*) desc;
```

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks to you for your website - It's helped me many a time ;)